# I am new to developing wcf services in sharepoint 2010

Tags: wcf

> Please guide me how i am satrt that wcf services development and deployment to sharepoint   and that webservices are called from other portals also which are developed by java developers.  Please Guide me to start prepare in a correct way

Thanks in advance

Regards,
Saida

Answer (score 0):

Developing WCF services becomes very easy if you use the templates provided by [CKS DEV](http://cksdev.codeplex.com/)
Also [this](http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.in/2011/03/sharepoint-2010-create-custom-wcf.html) article by Sohel can get you started.